# Notation for collection of elements that may contain duplicates

Tags: notation, terminology, multisets

I want to represent document `D` as a collection of words. I was inclined to do this with: `D = {w_1, w_2, ... }`. However, the curly brackets are often interpreted as sets that cannot have duplicates, while documents may contain duplicates.

(1) Are there other brackets or other notations that I can use to represent that ordered list ?

(2) What alternatives to use when that list is unordered ?

Comment: Does the fact that there are duplicates matter?  If not, then just let it be a set.  If it does matter, then does the order within matter?  If so, then just "arrays" (*compsci*) or "sequences" (*math*).  If not, then you can use "*bags*" (*compsci*) or "*multisets*" (*math*).  Different programming languages have possibly different names for such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a "multi-set" best answers the question in your title, people usually care about the order of the words in a document, in which case it's probably best to go with a sequence, and the notation for that is "$(w_i)$", or "$(w_i)_{i=1}^n$" if you want to fully decorate it.

To check if you want to go with multi-sets or sequences, ask yourself if you would consider "eat, cat, eat" and "eat, eat, cat" to be the same document or not. If the answer is "no", then go with sequences and the above notation. If the answer is "yes", then you're thinking of them as multi-sets, which sadly I don't believe have a standard notation.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I mean a sequence, then. What would be the notation if the first document was `['rose', 'rose', 'up','in','the','sky']`?

Comment: Parentheses, as in the answer: `('rose', 'rose', 'up','in','the','sky')`. Although your formatting makes me think what you're doing might fall a bit more in the computer science area, than just plain math, and that's enough of a difference that they might have slightly different notation conventions.

Comment: Though honestly, I would cope just fine if your paper used "$[w_1, w_2,...]$" notation. In programming languages there's usually a big difference between the two, but so long as you said "We will consider a document to be sequence of words, and denote it $D = ....$", and showed which form you were going to use, I'd be fine. But please don't use `{ }` - I'd constantly be thinking you were describing a set, and as you realized, those have the wrong semantics.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of an unordered list with possible duplicates is usually called a *multiset*. The notation conventions on this vary wildly. Some people use the same curly braces used for sets and make it clear that they are meant as multisets. Another option is to use square brackets. There is, unfortunately, not any universal convention for this kind of object.

Another possibility is to write multisets as linear cominations, so $\{a,b,b\}=[a,b,b]=a+2b$ for instance. This can be confusing if the elements are things which you can add though.

Comment: To add to the menagerie: Double curly braces seems nice for multi sets: $\{\{a, b, b\}\}$. It's the same notation as sets but multiple times...